# Converting list of varying-length elements to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Consider the following list of **vector** elements with varying length:

```
test = list(c(A = 1, B = 2), c(A = 3, C = 1), c(A = 9), c(A = 6, B = 7, C = 8))
```

I would like to convert the list to a dataframe, while matching the names of the elements in the following fashion:

```
 #  A  B  C
 #  1  2 NA
 #  3 NA  1
 #  9 NA NA
 #  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(plyr)

rbind.fill(lapply(test, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
#  A  B  C
#1 1  2 NA
#2 3 NA  1
#3 9 NA NA
#4 6  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I believe I made a mistake when coming up with this mock example. Although each element has column names, the elements are `numeric` not `dataframes`. Therefore, your suggested answer does not work. I will make the change in my post.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Can't believe I didn't figure out that one myself :)